# Custom titleView changes location after push and pop new screen in stack

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to implement custom `titleView` for navigation controller with "title" and "description" labels. If I placed this titleView on first VC, it looks good. If I push second VC into navigation stack and pop it, location of the `titleView` is changed.

`titleView`'s constraints:

```
titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
descriptionLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
titleLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor).isActive = true
descriptionLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.widthAnchor).isActive = true
titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
descriptionLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 2.0).isActive = true
```

In `viewDidLoad` of VC I use follow code to insert `titleView`:

```
navigationItem.titleView = BarTitleView()
navigationItem.titleView?.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: 44)
navigationItem.titleView?.updateConstraints()
```

I tried to insert follow lines into `viewWillAppear` (second VC has different bar buttons and it can be root of problem), but nothing changes

```
navigationItem.titleView?.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: 44)
navigationItem.titleView?.updateConstraints()
```

How can I fixed this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a Title and Subtitle in the Navigation bar without the need for Interface Builder and constraint modification.

My Function to create the title view looks as follows:

```
class func setTitle(title:String, subtitle:String) -> UIView {
    let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -8, width: 0, height: 0))

    titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
    titleLabel.text = title
    titleLabel.sizeToFit()

    let subtitleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 12, width: 0, height: 0))
    subtitleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    subtitleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    subtitleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
    subtitleLabel.text = subtitle
    subtitleLabel.sizeToFit()

    // Fix incorrect width bug
    if (subtitleLabel.frame.size.width > titleLabel.frame.size.width) {
        var titleFrame = titleLabel.frame
        titleFrame.size.width = subtitleLabel.frame.size.width
        titleLabel.frame = titleFrame
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    }

    let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: titleLabel.frame.size.width, height: titleLabel.frame.size.height))
    titleView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    titleView.addSubview(subtitleLabel)

    let widthDiff = subtitleLabel.frame.size.width - titleLabel.frame.size.width

    if widthDiff < 0 {
        let newX = widthDiff / 2
        subtitleLabel.frame.origin.x = abs(newX)
    } else {
        let newX = widthDiff / 2
        titleLabel.frame.origin.x = newX
    }

    return titleView
}
```

Then to use the title view in any view controller I just call this line:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = Functions.Views.setTitle(title: "Title String", subtitle: "Subtitle String")
```